# have error when install MongoDB Extension for Yii 2

Tags: mongodb, yii2, composer-php

I have wamp in my local system and the version of php is 5.5.12, also I installed the drivers and in the phpinfo it is shown that the mongodb is installed as well, but when I want to install mongo extension with composer I face error with the content of “first install mongo driver”. However I’ve tried a lot to install the mongo driver without any success. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `ini` files for PHP - one for CGI and one for CLI version. You need to check if this extension is added in both of them. This line (or similar) should be added and uncommented.

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

In new Wamp these two files are just one in fact (the second one is symlinked to the first one) - if this is the case you need to check if this extension is installed properly.

Ini files can be there:

```
wamp\bin\php\php{version}
wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin
```

Also check [this link](http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way) for help.